# What code is faster ("if null || undefined" vs "call assertion")?

Tags: javascript, performance

To make my code more readable and cleaner I want to switch to approach when all the value checks I am gonna do using dedicated assertion functions. Basically instead of "if" statements there is gonna be function calls with "error" argument.

I am worrying if that approach will make my code run slower: a) function call is heavier. b) string value is always allocated instead it is allocated in if block.

Here is two fragments of code as an example:

1.

```js
assertIsSet = (value, error) => { if (value === null || value === undefined) throw new Error(error); }

...

assertIsSet(options, 'options argument is required.');

...
```

2.

```js
if (options === null || options === undefined) throw new Error('options argument is required.')
```

I don't know enough about modern JS engines and how they compile/optimise the code, and I don't think the difference is gonna be noticeable in 99% cases, but I am creating complex canvas based app where I fight for every 5ms.

What do you think guys, is my concern reasonable?

Thanks!

Comment: Depending on how the function is setup you could use this... `arguments.length == 0 && throw new Error('...')` or something similar

Comment: The advantage of a function is that you can fix it and not have to change anything else in the code. Specifically, you could make it become a "null function" once you're done debugging without having to remove all the calls from everywhere. (i.e. `assertIsSet = (value, error) => { return }` would make it run without the actual assertion—although in JS you still get the expression of the assertion computed.)

Comment: @AlexisWilke, null function is a good trick! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSBench.me is generally useful if you want to check code for its performance.

I've set up two jsbench.me versions to test this:

1. https://jsbench.me/anjjrl78hi/1
2. https://jsbench.me/anjjrl78hi/2

Running the first version a couple of times did not yield significant differences.

When "globally" defining the function (version 2), it was a bit more biased to the `if` version. From my point of view, JS needs to check in the various scopes, where to find the defined function. But still, it wasn't really performing worse than the `if`.

So if you're not using `assertIsSet` too often, you may get the best results by inlining it. Instead of doing that manually, you could "compile" your code into something that inlines your `assertIsSet` calls (maybe a Webpack plugin or something like that might help). Or have a look at WebAssembly, if you need performance critical things.

Comment: Thanks for response! About compiling code - yes, I think I will spend time to learn it, google closure compiler as I heard also gives some performance boost, is it truth? WebAssembly is dream for now, codebase is too complex for 1 to 1 porting, from JS to C/C++. I use prototype chaining, C++ has classes, I use object literals, C++ has classes, need to write canvas api bridge and a lot of stuff... unfortunately it's almost impossible now, but I sometimes read about wasm news.

Comment: Usually, you compile from a typed language to asm.js, which is a subset of JavaScript and can be optimized very much by the various JavaScript engines. With "compile" I meant you could add a build step to your JS and let some script inline the `assertIsSet` calls, meaning "replace with the `if`". But in any case, if you need high-performance code running in the browser, do have a look at WebAssembly.

Answer (score 0):

Made up some perf test, ran 1 000 000 times those two approaches, here is result

```js
function perf_test_take() {
    let options = {};
    console.time('assertion');
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) assertIsSet(options, 'pretty long string pretty long string pretty long string pretty long string');
    console.timeEnd('assertion');
    console.time('if statement');
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        if (options === null || options === undefined) {
            throw new Error('pretty long string pretty long string pretty long string pretty long string');
        }
    }
    console.timeEnd('if statement');
}

function perf_test_take_kickoff() {
    console.log('take 1');
    perf_test_take();
    console.log('take 2');
    perf_test_take();
    console.log('take 3');
    perf_test_take();
    console.log('take 4');
    perf_test_take();
    console.log('take 5');
    perf_test_take();
    console.log('take 6');
    perf_test_take();
}

// OUTPUT

// take 1
assertion: 3.5927734375ms
if statement: 2.337890625ms

// take 2
assertion: 0.524169921875ms
if statement: 0.7998046875ms

// take 3
assertion: 0.54296875ms
if statement: 0.535888671875ms

// take 4
assertion: 0.5322265625ms
if statement: 0.47998046875ms

// take 5
assertion: 0.51611328125ms
if statement: 0.5009765625ms

// take 6
assertion: 0.546875ms
if statement: 0.503173828125ms
```

I thinks it's not case!